# More general pattern matching

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

If I have a function, for example

```
f :: Int -> Int -> Int
f x y = x + y
```

and I want to have different functionality based on the parameters, I use pattern matching.
I have only found the syntax of how to match against concrete values, e.g.

```
f 0 y = y
```

Is it possible to match against something more general?
I would like to have different functionality in the case that the first parameter is less than 0. A second case could be if the second parameter exceeds a certain value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use guards:

```
f x y | x < 0 = ...
f x y | y > someValue = ...
f x y | otherwise = ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure, there is a mechanism called [guards](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pattern_guard) for that:

```
f x y | x < 0 = y
```